# Python HTTP request resulting in 503 service unavailable

Tags: python, api

Keep getting service unavailable error when I try a GET request, you can see and run the code here
https://repl.it/@HarrysCoding/Yahoo-Market-Feed

This is the code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/trending.json?access_token=b03eef9a78c240a62d44c71734792614ead9d83d'
trending_response = requests.get(url)
print(trending_response)
```

However, when I run the code locally on my pc it works fine, and the url below loads fine too in browser:

https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/trending.json?access_token=b03eef9a78c240a62d44c71734792614ead9d83d

What's causing the 503 error when running GET request remotely?

Comment: It looks like a protective measure against abuse by stockwits API/Cloudflare. If you look at the returned data with this `print(trending_response.__dict__)` you will see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you Sirajus, any reason why I can successfully perform GET request locally